# get first following page value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <toc-item>
        <toc-title>A</toc-title>
        <page>11/4/10A</page>
        <page>cclxxi</page>
    </toc-item>
    <toc-item>
        <toc-title>B</toc-title>
        <page>11/5/1A</page>
    </toc-item>
    <toc-item>
        <toc-title>C</toc-title>
        <page>11/4</page>
        <page>cclxxii</page>
    </toc-item>

    <toc-item>
        <toc-title>B</toc-title>
        <page>11/5/1A</page>
    </toc-item>
    <toc-item>
        <toc-title>C</toc-title>
        <page>11/4</page>
        <page>cclxxiiv</page>
    </toc-item>
</root>
```

and below XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="root">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="toc-item">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="toc-title">
        <td class="toc-title">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="content-style">
        <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@font-style">
                <span class="{$fontStyle}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <span class="{concat('format-',./@format)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </span>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::page[1])">
                     <td class="toc-page" valign="bottom">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="first"/>                  
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
        <xsl:variable name="pgn">
            <xsl:value-of select="./following::page/following-sibling::page[1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pgn"/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
        <a name="{concat('pg_',$pgn)}"/>

    </xsl:template>  


 <xsl:template match="page" mode="two">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
        <a name="{concat('pg_',.)}"/>
    </xsl:template> 
  </xsl:transform>
```

here i'm trying to get the next `page` which has a preceding `page`, but here when i'm doing i get all the next pages.

Here is a working demo.
http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rM4

please let me know how can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can remove the templates matching `content-style` and `page` with mode `two` because they are currently not used.

Comment: Could you include your desired outout (as @mattias_h already implied)? Otherwise it's difficult to conclusively deduce your intention. Since you wrote the template matching `<page>` with mode `two` maybe you just want the first and second matches of `<page>` to be handled by the modes `one` and `two` accordingly? In this case you could simply extend the matching criterion which would simplify your XSLT a little bit.

Comment: Please include your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood how the output should look like, but if you change

```
<xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
<xsl:variable name="pgn">
  <xsl:value-of select="./following::page/following-sibling::page[1]"/>   
  ...
```

into

```
<xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
<xsl:variable name="pgn">
  <xsl:value-of select="./following::page[preceding-sibling::page][1]"/>
  ...
```

you'll get the following output:

```
<td class="toc-title">A</td>
<td class="toc-page" valign="bottom">11/4/10A</td>
<?pb label='cclxxii'?><a name="pg_cclxxii"></a>

<td class="toc-title">B</td>
<td class="toc-page" valign="bottom">11/5/1A</td>

<td class="toc-title">C</td>
<td class="toc-page" valign="bottom">11/4</td>
<?pb label='cclxxiiv'?><a name="pg_cclxxiiv"></a>

<td class="toc-title">B</td>
<td class="toc-page" valign="bottom">11/5/1A</td>

<td class="toc-title">C</td>
<td class="toc-page" valign="bottom">11/4</td>
<?pb label=''?><a name="pg_"></a>
```

The difference is: instead of selecting all following sibling pages of all following pages, only the first following page that has has preceding sibling page is selected.

In case the output should look in another way, please add the desired output to your question to avoid misunderstandings.

Your adjusted [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rM4/2).

As mentioned in the comments, the last page that has no following page that can be linked to would have an empty link. This can be avoided by following adjustment:

```
<xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
<xsl:variable name="pgn">
   <xsl:value-of select="./following::page[preceding-sibling::page][3]"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="$pgn != ''">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
        <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pgn"/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <a name="{concat('pg_',$pgn)}"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Result for the last page:

```
<td class="toc-title">C</td>
<td class="toc-page" valign="bottom">11/4</td>
```

Adjusted in the [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rM4/3)

Comment: I guess the last the processing instruction is not supposed to be broken?

Comment: @MarcusRickert Thanks for the question, as I'm not sure what the OP wants to have as link for the last page that has no further link target, too. I'll add this in the answer, maybe this will result in a follow up question by OP soon.